# Relaxation vs Laziness

Tags: sutras, five-hindrances, guidance

In karniyametta sutta, Lord Buddha advised us to be relaxed and not to cling to the work.

How can I recognise relaxation from laziness ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you can't recognize the difference it is laziness.

**Relaxation is samadhi**: the collection of mind around an object of meditation.

When we speak of conventional relaxation, what we really mean is letting the defilements do whatever they want to the mind.

Answer (score 1):

Relaxation is essential for everyone to recharge after work. It aids in maintaining and restoring our physical and mental well-being. Buddha did not advocate against relaxation. However, he discouraged laziness, which hinders progress and success in both everyday life and the path to enlightenment, as it impedes achievement in all endeavors, according to the sutta.

Answer (score 1):

Kusītārambhavatthusutta best describes laziness in eight grounds, according to this sutta laziness is when you are held back from attaining the unattained, achieving the unachieved, and so on depending on your case for varying excuses. If your relaxation technique doesn't restrain you from accomplishing that (your goal) it is not laziness. Relaxation should aid your progress; laziness hinders your progress. This should be simple.

Answer (score 0):

This point in Karniyametta Sutta is to be smart in ones undertaking as elaborated in:

> (1) Young brahmin, there is work that is **great** in goal, **great** in task, **great** in busyness, **great** in
>   undertakings, but when it ***fails***, is **small** in fruit [consequence].
>
> (2) Young brahmin, there is work that is **small** in goal, with **little** busyness, **few** in external affairs,
>   **few** in undertakings, but when it ***succeeds***, is **great** in fruit.
>
> (3) Young brahmin, there is work that is **small** in goal, **few** in task, **few** in external affairs, **small** in
>   undertakings, but when it ***fails***, is **small** in fruit [consequence].
>
> (4) Young brahmin, there is work that is **great** in goal, **great** in task, **great** busyness, **great** in undertaking, when it ***succeeds***, is **great** in fruit.

[(Brahma,vihāra) Subha Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/38.6-Brahmavihara-Subha-S-m99-piya.pdf)

Further elaboration is given in trading and spiritual life in the Sutta.

If one is lazy one procrastinates and/or does not take any initiative than the most productive and effective course of action. The Sutta does not say one should not cling to work thought this is something one should do, but one should be or less work but being more productive and effective.

Footnote 151 in [Karanīya Metta Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/38.3-Karaniya-Metta-S-khp-9-Sn-1.8-piya.pdf), tr. by Piya Tan:

> having with little busyness, appa,kicco. A renunciant should not have a busy life: see nn at (Brahma,vihāra)
>   Subha S (M 99.5/2:197), SD 38.6; also above, (3.1.2).